# SQL-How to bring second cell value of BRI into new column till I encounter new BRI value

Tags: sql, oracle

[PL/SQL view script/query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vH7b.jpg)

View above picture for clarity. Question below:

I have a query that generate following output:

```
| columnA | columnB |
---------------------
|      BRI|       XX|
---------------------
|      BRD|       1J|
---------------------
|      BRD|       2Q|
---------------------
|      BRI|       YY|
---------------------
|      BRD|       8X|
---------------------
|      BRD|       5Z|
---------------------
```

Here BRI and BRD is constant.
Is there a solution that I could generate another columnC which is exactly the same as columnB for BRI , 
and having value from columnB of the upper BRI moving downwards for BRD till we encounter a new BRI value. 
Below is the expecting output:

```
| columnA | columnB |columnC  |
------------------------------
|      BRI|       XX|       XX|     
------------------------------
|      BRD|       1J|       XX|     
-------------------------------
|      BRD|       2Q|       XX|     
-------------------------------
|      BRI|       YY|       YY|     
-------------------------------
|      BRD|       8X|       YY|     
-------------------------------
|      BRD|       5Z|       YY|     
-------------------------------
```

Comment: You need something to guarantee the sort order.  It's not `columnB` so what is it?

Comment: yes that is a constraint which cannot be imposed. The output is actually representation via an external table with (columnA and Column B), to ensure order, we are imposing 'order by rowid asc' before loading it into a real table. You may impose rownum to fix the order of selection.